# express routing and path params

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have the following routing in app.js

```
app.use("/api/:phone/stuff", userRoutes);
```

In userRoutes, I have the following

```
userRoutes.get("/", userController.getStuff);
```

The client (Android app, retrofit) requests the following url: GET /api/+155555555/stuff, in userService I have getStuff method **which is executed** as expected, meaning it routes it well.

in a validation middleware, I see that `req.originalUrl` contains the url as expected but when viewing `req.params`, it is an empty object. I was expecting it to link the phone part of the url to :phone param so I will have `req.params.phone`.

I thought the problem was the + sign but it is urlencoded and even without it, it didn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default express router does not inherit parent router params

```
const userRoutes = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
```

should do the trick

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router